# How could I write that code more clearly?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I mean, that code should be written more clearly. Can you help me, have you yet one idea ? I Need to assign the value `list_new` to variable depending on the list value. The list value is not constant and `list_new` it's also not constant and depends on the list value. Wenn I have for example `[1,1,1]` then I have new list with three values also list_new = `["AS1","AS2","AS3"]`.

```
[power_a, power_b, power_c] = [0,1, 1]
list_new = ["AS2","AS3"]
counter = 0

if power_a == 1:
    power_a = list_new[counter]
    print power_a
    counter += 1

if power_b == 1:
    power_b = list_new[counter]
    print power_b
    counter += 1

if power_c == 1:
    power_c = list_new[counter]
    print power_c
    counter += 1
```

Comment: You should add a description of what it is your code actually does into the question (your title should also reflect the purpose of the code, not what you want to get out of the review).

Comment: This appears to be stripped from all context. At Code Review, we need context to be able to write good answers.

Comment: Your edit didn't fix much I'm afraid. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] and [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, so this is going to be just code refactoring

since you are doing the same thing in 3 places, you can reduce it to a for loop

```
powers = [0, 1, 1]
list_new = ["AS2","AS3"]
list_of_names = list_new[:]
for i in xrange(len(powers)):
    if powers[i] == 1:
        powers[i] = list_of_names.pop(0)
        print powers[i]
```

Comment: If you are doing `list.pop(0)` you probably want a `collections.deque`, which has \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ `deque.popleft`, instead of lists \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I shouldn't have modified list_new, I should have created a copy. Will ammend to iterate correctly over powers

Comment: You could also reverse the list, allowing you to use `pop()`, since you are copying it anyways.